# selecting particula tag in XML jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have xml and `id`tag is repeating but I want to select only outer tag only. for example

```
<getProfileResponse
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <getProfileResult>
        <ns2:retrieveProfileResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.lms.ama.com/">
            <clubMemberEnrollment>
                <details>
                    <isn>0</isn>
                </details>
                <id>0</id>
                <main_member/>
            </clubMemberEnrollment>
            <gender>F</gender>
            <id>300000223</id>
            <idWithSuffix>300000223</idWithSuffix>
            <maritalStatus>S</maritalStatus>
        </ns2:retrieveProfileResponse>
    </getProfileResult>
</getProfileResponse>
```

When I use `$(data).find("id").text()` then I am getting 0300000223 rather 300000223. Kindly help me somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do that , the values are appended. (`<id>0</id>` +  `<id>300000223</id>`)

You might want to try `:last`

```
$(data).find("id:last").text()
```

This will only work if `<id>300000223</id>` is after `<clubMemberEnrollment>`

A better solution is to use this :

```
 $(xml).find("id")
       .filter(function ( ){return  
               $(this).closest('clubMemberEnrollment').length==0})
       .text() ;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6et8u51y/90/)